# packery/isotope/masonry lightbox album laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-masonry, lightbox2, albumart

well first of all, im no expert in javascript, ive been spending few days tinkering with masonry, lightbox to create UI like in picture1, any suggestion of how to create something like it, in example of picture1.

there are 4 albums with fixed size, inside there are preview of thumbnail, only few are shown, if you click the album it show lightbox with left/right arrow navigation to all photo inside album.

so any suggestion or code example... ive been spending few days to tinker it on my own but with my limited knowledge of javascript/jquery/sass/less im lost.

plus, laravel question since packery/masonry/isotope need to use our own css, what is the best way to implement each different div grid class to match the column container

```html
@foreach($gallery->photos as $g)
<div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
  <img src="{{url($g->file_path)}}" alt="">
</div>
@endforeach
```

[PICTURE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sb7c.jpg)

Comment: looking for this ? http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html or http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html

Comment: Thankyou, perhaps thats what im searching for, yes i just dont know yet how to wrap it like in the example since css done by us and i got low knowledge in javascript, to arrange itself based on image size